# Error in creating scss map

Tags: sass

I'm using sass 3.4.5. I'm trying to declare a map which has gotten me this error:

**Invalid CSS after "  'blue'": expected ")", was ": #3498db,"**

```
$base-color: (
  'blue': #3498db,
  'green': #2ecc71,
  'bg': #f3f3f3
);
```

Is there any wrong with my code?

Comment: Double check your versions.  If you're getting that error, you aren't running Sass 3.4.5.

Comment: I'm working on a rails project, which uses sass-rails 4.0.3.
And `sass -v` in terminal indicate it's 3.4.5.
Any recommendation?

Comment: it looks fine and it works in http://sassmeister.com/gist/abb5c540f02d26c9180b